# Resizable container in flex box biased towards one side

Tags: html, css

Why is the separator between the 2 pane elements in this example "biased" towards the secondary pane? By biased I mean that dragging the resize handle results in the handle snapping left of where the cursor is, pulling it to one side while dragging. Setting `flex:none` on the pane results in the resize dragging working normally, but then the content overflows the parent element, which I don't want. Is there a way to fix this in pure CSS without any JS?

```css
div#main-panel {
  flex: auto;
}

.horizontal-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.pane {
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid black;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.left-pane {
  min-width: 10%;
  max-width: 50%;
  border: solid red;
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
long + long

<div class="horizontal-container" id="main-panel">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong 
loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong             loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
  <div class="pane secondary-pane">
    loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
</div>

long + short
<div class="horizontal-container" id="main-panel">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
  <div class="pane secondary-pane">
    short
  </div>
</div>
short + short
<div class="horizontal-container" id="main-panel">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    short
  </div>
  <div class="pane secondary-pane">
    short
  </div>
</div>
short + long
<div class="horizontal-container" id="main-panel">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    short
  </div>
  <div class="pane secondary-pane">
    loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because a fixed width of flex child will not be treated as is, it will shrink. So you can add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `left-pane` so that it wouldn't shrink:

```css
div#main-panel {
  flex: auto;
}

.horizontal-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.pane {
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid black;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.left-pane {
  min-width: 10%;
  max-width: 50%;
  border: solid red;
  resize: horizontal;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-container" id="main-panel">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    sample text
  </div>
  <div class="pane secondary-pane">
    loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

By adding `flex-grow: 0` to the `left-pane`:

```css
div#main-panel {
  flex: auto;
}

.horizontal-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.pane {
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid black;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.left-pane {
  min-width: 10%;
  max-width: 50%;
  border: solid red;
  resize: horizontal;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
long + long

<div class="horizontal-container" id="main-panel">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong 
loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong             loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
  <div class="pane secondary-pane">
    loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
</div>

long + short
<div class="horizontal-container" id="main-panel">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
  <div class="pane secondary-pane">
    short
  </div>
</div>
short + short
<div class="horizontal-container" id="main-panel">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    short
  </div>
  <div class="pane secondary-pane">
    short
  </div>
</div>
short + long
<div class="horizontal-container" id="main-panel">
  <div class="pane left-pane">
    short
  </div>
  <div class="pane secondary-pane">
    loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the `left-pane` has very long content as well? Is there a way to set the initial width of the element to 0px or something like that? Setting `width` prevents it from being resized at all, and `inline-size` doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Also it seems like if I remove the long content from the right pane, it stops working. Is there a solution that works regardless of the content width?

Comment: you can set the width with width and still make it resizable. It can't be zero because you set `min-width: 10%`, you should remove that if you want 0 width, but I don't think it can be 0 because it needs to have the scroll and the drag button

Comment: you can add `flex-grow: 0` to the left-pane if you want to remove the second content

Comment: setting width: 10% and removing min-width makes it non-resizable

Comment: sorry, I don't get what you want, maybe you could edit your question with your latest code

Comment: Added all the cases I want to handle. I'm trying to figure out if there's a solution for all of them. I know some of them can be handled with different combinations of flex-grow and flex-shrink, but I'm hoping there's a generic solution that covers everything.